# Visual Studio 2012 Stuck Initialising

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've had this message for awhile in Visual Studio 2012.

[image]

I have installed RxCpp via Nuget. When i use rxcpp::from(merged).merge(i) Visual Studio spends a good hour parse solution files. I am now stuck on this, it started at 0 of 7 files, it'now 0 of 11.... a number of hours later.

https://rxcpp.codeplex.com/

Any clues what i going on here?

The include is in the project's main.cpp is fine until i use a function from this library.

Some sources have suggested Project C++ options and changing Disable Database to false. Which it already is. Others, suggest restarting solution, but we get the same thing.

Totally lost.

Comment: The issue you recorded for the project is far better than this question.  Wait for the project owners to respond.  You can tinker with any add-in you installed in VS in the meantime.

Comment: No worries. I kinda hoped it was a generic VS2012 issue. :)

Comment: http://xanthelasma3.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=3507589&item=2044